# Take string received from Web Service and populate class

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

I have a file of classes that I generated from an xsd file using the XSD Tool.  I receive an XML string response from a web service.  How do I populate the generated classes with the string xml received?

Comment: In which programming language are you trying to populate classes?

Comment: The process of populating classes as you describe is usually called unmarshalling. I'm not familiar with C#, but google can probably help you put given that term.

Comment: What kind of web service is this? You usually just  use "Add Service Reference" to point to the WSDL of the service, then you don't have to play with XML at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer to generate the class.

```
TheClass result = null;
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TheClass));
using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using(XmlReader XmlReader = new XmlReader(reader))
    {
        result = dcs.ReadObject() as TheClass;
    }
}
```